Converting short current pulses to TTL levels so they can be read with microcontroller
I'm trying to communicate with a device that encodes information in the timing/presence of its current consumption: when it wants to send information, it causes 100ns, 40mA current spikes to happen (without modifying the supply voltage too much). I would like to detect these pulses from a 3.3V microcontroller.
Here's an oscilloscope image of one such pulse, measured across a shunt resistor of 10 ohm on the low side of the device (the blue channel is the current; 100ns per division; 200mV corresponding to 20 mA per division).

Each such pulse seems to be accompanied with a matching negative pulse . If it's a lot easier to do so, we can assume this is always the case, and detect such a pulse pair as one 'event'. The pulses in a pulsepair are 250 us apart; the pulse pairs amongst them are at least 1 ms apart from each other.

Here's a big picture scope image, showing all pulses:
the blue channel is the current; 2 ms per division; 200mV corresponding to 20mA per division

I would like to detect those pulses on a 3.3V microcontroller (the RP2040), but have some problems:

the voltage at the shunt resistor is too low to use with digital IO
the pulse duration is too short to reliably catch with the built-in ADC
the negative pulses might damage the microcontroller (?)

Is there a way to condition these pulses so they are easier to read out? I only want to detect when the pulses happen, not their current or duration.

The 1st scope picture with a 100 ns timebase doesn't appear to show a negative current pulse but show what appears to be "ringing", whereas the 2nd scope picture with a 2 ms timebase does show a negative current pulse. Perhaps the negative pulse in the 2nd scope picture is an artefact of the measurement. How is the shunt resistor being probed?

@ChesterGillon there is a negative current pulse as well, but it's always after the first pulse (and too long after it to fit both in the same window). I'll add a picture of such a negative pulse. The shunt resistor is on the low side of the device: the ground clamp of the probe is connected to the side of the resistor connected to ground, the probe is connected to the side of the shunt resistor connected to the device.

So the device uses nearly no current the rest of the time, besides these 40mA pulses? How much voltage drop is allowed?

@Unimportant seems to be that way, yes. Ideally, don't drop too much voltage, I think 1V would be okay (based on nothing but gut feeling). It still works fine with a 10 ohm shunt.

A monostable circuit build from fast transistors (BF… grade) could do that.

stupid question, if this is a current pulse and you want a higher voltage, why not simply use a higher-value resistor than the very low 10Ω?

@MarcusMüller because I'm worried the higher valued resistor will have too much voltage drop (but I guess I can test it)

why not then use a larger resistor and a pair of TVS diodes against VCC and GND of your MCU?

@MarcusMüller just tested it, that totally works :) I guess I made it more complicated than it actually was. if you make it an answer, I'll gladly accept it

The easiest way here seems to be choosing shunt resistor large enough to give you the required voltage for your MCU to register.
To protect your MCU against overvoltage, a TVS diode to the supply voltage and the ground potential of your microcontroller should work.

We want to invert the negative pulse, and amplify both to logic levels.  The signal level is high enough that a modest amplifier can be used, single BJTs for example:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Some temperature compensation is probably desirable on the base bias dividers, to compensate for the VBE negative tempco.  This will read statically "on" (both outputs low) at high temperatures (100°C+?).
Don't take the resistor values too seriously, either; CircuitLab isn't a particularly good simulator, and I would expect values to change in practice.

As you can see, this can also be used to stretch the pulse length -- try adjusting R2, R3.  Probably, these can be internal weak pull-ups, and an edge-triggered interrupt or timer can be used to capture the event.
Probably an edge-triggered input can be used without much pulse stretching, in which case the type of transistor, and size of pull-up, will be less specific.  If edge triggering is not available, stretching the pulse to a few clock cycles is most likely sufficient to get some kind of event through.  RP2040 is a quite capable platform, many options should be suitable.

Using a CMOS Op Amp as a Set/Reset Register with 10% hysteresis is easier. With an R2RIO type, CMOS uses any Vdd.

Your values may vary.
This is inverting but could be changed.
